# maven: how to copy EAR from Maven repository to websphere server path

Tags: java, maven, ftp, websphere, devops

We have generated EAR for the application using maven, EAR is available in maven repository and using websphere as application server.

As part of CI/CD, we need to move the maven generated EAR stored in repository to another server in which websphere is running.

How to transfer this EAR to another server for deployment?

Comment: from where? Jenkins?

Comment: Make use of scp https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp.

Comment: from Gitlab repository to server path... can we do this while building EAR from pom.xml?